# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql' when I use Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I created an inventory program wherein I used pymysql. It's running smoothly when I run it using Pycharm, but when I converted it into a .exe file, it shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'"

[image: Here's the image of the error]

I tried finding for solution online but they doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem with pypdfium2 because one dll was not loaded. I solved it with adding `--collect-all pypdfium2`.